# Conversion of huge Sparse Csr_matrix tp Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.7

I have a huge sparse matrix created using the TFIDF vectorizer. The size is (192134, 76954). However, I had to convert this into pandas Dataframe. However while trying with the

pd.DataFrame(vectors.toarray()) or 
pd.DataFrame(vectors.todense())

(where vectors is the sparse matrix in sparse.csr_matrix form), gives me memory error.

Could someone help me to convert such huge sparse matrix into pandas dataframe.

Thanks in advance :)